# which or who in "the body, authority, entity or person which establishes"

Tags: relative-pronouns, which-who

*... the body, authority, entity or person which establishes...*

Is it correct to use "which" in this case? Or should it rather be "who", since the last element of the list is a person?

Comment: Yes, when working with a list, the most appropriate one for the whole class would be a better choice. *Who* does not work with "body", "authority" or "entity," but *which* can technically work with "person" ("person" is also a thing in the same class for the purpose of the context here). HTH.

Comment: *That* sounds better to me than either *who* or *which*.

Comment: I agree with @Kris - 'which' is what I would use.

Comment: 'That' seems to me to be optimal.

Answer (score -1):

In general, as Huddleston & Pullum (2002) note, the relative pronoun matches the last coordinate:

> ... the body, authority, entity or person *who* establishes...

That said, given the number of inanimate coordinates ("body," "authority," and "entity") at the start of the noun phrase, and since this is a restrictive relative clause, I think most speakers would prefer to avoid the problem by using *that*:

> ... the body, authority, entity or person *that* establishes...

Comment: Very dubious downvote. Attested, attributed ... and I'm with you that 'that' harmonises best here.

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but it was entirely deserved, because *that* should never ever be used for *person.* I do normally downvote any mention of H&P but in this case they've got it right, so my downvote on *that* is cancelled out by their *who* as last-coordinating.

Comment: @AndrewLeach H&P say that "who" is more common with personal antecedents, but that "that" is perfectly acceptable. I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: Oh, OK. Downvote for H&P, as usual.